# only the first iteration works on this loop why is that?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Only the first iteration in my loop is inserted in the array I created.

```
for ($i=1; $i < 2; $i++) { 
  $this->data['checks'] = array(
     'ques'.$i => $this->input->post('questionNumber'.$i),
  );            
}
```

Comment: `$i < 2` should be `$i <= 2` if you need 2

Comment: On second iteration `$i` is 2. `2 < 2` - false.

Comment: You'll also need to append a new element each time or it overwrites: `$this->data['checks'][] =`

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i=0; $i < 2; $i++) { 
  $this->data['checks'] = array(
     'ques'.$i => $this->input->post('questionNumber'.$i),
  );            
}
```

you already have it set to 1, so it only needs to loop once more. Setting it to 0 will fix the issue of one loop.

Comment: Do we really need to answer this? The comments already solve the problem and this question has no value to future visitors.

Comment: and then somewhere there is a question zero :D

Comment: look at the times, from when I posted, to those comments. 1 minute difference. So logically you can assume that I was probably writing my response when they posted those comments. Also I think, the explanation I gave, will be of help to other noobs.

Comment: You'll also need to append a new element each time or it overwrites: `$this->data['checks'][] =`